# Easy Language/IDE to Develop GUI Program?

Tags: user-interface, ide, wysiwyg

I'm planning on developing an Windows desktop-based GUI application, and I don't have a clue which language or IDE to choose. I'd REALLY like something with a WYSIWYG GUI editor. My application will rely on web-based XML feeds, so built in support for that would be great. I don't want the application to have any dependencies or require admin rights to run. Cross-platform is nice, not not required.

I'm willing to learn a new language if that's necessary.

Comment: You say "cross-platform is nice, but not required". If it's not cross-platform, what platform should it run on?

Answer (score 1):

Delphi is well reputed for Windows GUI application developpment. It's even a 'RAD' Studio (rapid application development studio) as they call it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Delphi.  Alternatively FreePascal with its Lazarus IDE is pretty much an open-source Delphi clone, which while not as polished, offers cross-platform support.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, I will definitely go for C#.
If you know c++ and have MFC experiences, it should be fairly easy to learn.

Yes, it has WYSIWYG GUI editor.

> Designing a User Interface (Visual C#) 
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173080(v=vs.80).aspx

and it seems this is what you are looking for?

> SyndicationFeed Class
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does C# require the user to have .NET installed?

Comment: It seems it does. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146369/how-can-i-deploy-a-c-application-if-users-dont-have-net-installed

Answer (score 0):

There are several variants.

***Windows only***

**C# + MSVS**:
One of the best choices on *Windows* platform today

- +good documentation
- +big developers community
- -you need a system which has .net installed.

**Delphi**

- +easy to start
- all-in-one tool with GUI editor
- not very widespread

  ---

***Cross-platfrom***

**Qt** or **wxWidgets** or some other toolsets

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a free solution, you can use [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/), which is a free IDE for C# or VB.NET, and has a GUI designer similar to the one in Visual Studio. You should be able to use any classes and libraries from/for the .NET Framework.

You'll need the .NET Framework, but starting with Windows Vista it's installed by default (.NET Framework 3.0, I think).