# How to make simple C# app which works on both Win 7 and Win 10 without installation

Tags: c#, .net, windows

We built a simple C# Windows Application with VS 2017 targeting .NET Framework 4.6.

The app works fine as a .exe file on other Windows 10 PCs. However, some PCs are still running on Windows 7 and we would like the app to be able to work on Winodws 7 as well as Windows 10 without further installations of .NET framework or App installation. In other words, just putting .exe file of the app on Windows 7 or Windows 10 and it works.

I thought to target a .NET framework 3.5 or 4 but this needed further installations on either Windows PCs.

Any help from the professionals is appreciated.

Comment: @John the problem is, that he doesn't want to install a .Net Framework on the target PC but package it into the app, like some dll. Which AFAIK is not possible.

Comment: I think can’t https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146369/how-can-i-deploy-a-c-sharp-application-if-users-dont-have-net-installed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I deploy a C# application if users don't have .NET installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146369/how-can-i-deploy-a-c-sharp-application-if-users-dont-have-net-installed)